# How can you tell if the wires are male to male, male to female, or female to female on schematics?

Tags: wiring

[image]

This is a schematic for my UV reader.

Comment: You don't. Select as appropriate. That is not a schematic by the way. It's a wiring diagram. Not the same thing.

Comment: why do you need to know?

Answer (score 4):

That's not what we call a schematic<sup>1</sup>. That's a wiring diagram.

To determine what type of ready-made jumper leads you require you need to determine whether each device has a pin header or socket header. You can guess some of these or get the information from datasheets or product photos if you don't have the parts to hand.

- The Arduino board has socket headers.
- The red and blue boards appear to be plugged into the breadboard so they must have pins on the underside. You won't be connecting directly to them but will be plugging pins into the breadboard holes vertically below them in your diagram.
- The breadboard takes pins.

For the circuit shown you can use pin-pin jumper leads for all connections.

---

<sup>1</sup> The reason that "cartoon" doesn't count as a schematic is that it doesn't explain the "schema" of the circuit. Proper schematic diagrams use symbols, component designators (R1, R2, C1, U1, etc.) and should be laid out so that the operation of the circuit can be understood. Generally they are drawn with positive voltages towards the top, negative towards the bottom (so that current flows from top to bottom) and signal flows as much as possible from left to right.

Comment: Frizzy pictures are not schematics. You are also missing power connections unless you are powering with USB.

Comment: but but but... current flows from the negative!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Your physics have no power here!

Answer (score 1):

Pin -->
Socket ---<

Schematics are "logical" and not required to be "physical".

Wires are always "male" unless terminated with sockets.